# Git auto-pull using cronjob

Tags: git, cron

I was trying to create a cronjob with a task to do a `git pull` every minute to keep my production site in sync with my master branch.

The git pull needs to be done by the system user `nobody`, due to the permissions problem. However it seems that the `nobody` account is not allowed run commands. So I have to create tasks as the `root` user.

The crontab entry I tried:

```
*/1 * * * * su -s /bin/sh nobody -c 'cd ~heilee/www && git pull -q origin master' >> ~/git.log
```

It doesn't work, and I don't know how to debug it.

Could anyone help?

UPDATE1: the `git pull` command itself is correct. I can run it without errors.

Comment: What happens when you run the command itself in a shell?

Comment: Do you have a user named `git.log`?

Comment: @Tom it does run if I run the command itself.

Comment: You'll want to update the output to write to the absolute path of the log. The tilde (~) is a relative path to YOUR home directory. I don't think this will fix your problem, but you should have it end with `... >> /var/log/git.log`

Comment: Because `git pull` automatically runs `git merge` which may fail with conflicts, and leave things in a state that is non-trivial for an automated script to fix, I would highly dis-recommend doing this on any repository that has even a remote chance of anything other than that one job causing updates that may prove to be incompatible. Use `git fetch` instead, and periodically do a manual merge.

Comment: if `git` has to use `ssh`, see [git push via cron](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7994663/4279)

Comment: GitHub renamed its default branch from `master` to `main` in 2020.  If these answers aren't working, make sure you're indeed pulling from a `master` branch and if not, change that value to match your remote branch.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Solution:

```
*/1 * * * * su -s /bin/sh nobody -c 'cd ~dstrt/www && /usr/local/bin/git pull -q origin master'
```

Comment: doesn't work for me on ubuntu 10.04 server. 3 different errors (~, /local/ and -q all cause problems)

Comment: `*/1 * * * * su -s /bin/sh nobody -c 'cd /home/dstrt/src/project && /usr/bin/git pull origin master'` works better for me: ~ expansion more reliable, different path to git for my distro, and -q option for git should be after `pull` or not at all, otherwise git barfs.

Comment: */1 * * * * /bin/sh -c 'cd /path/to/repo && /usr/bin/git pull -q origin master' worked for me.

Comment: `*/1 * * * * /bin/sh -c 'cd /home/userName/repo && /usr/bin/git pull -q origin master'`
It is ok for me. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.02.

Comment: @kayue - what does the script do step by step?

Answer (score 13):

While you do need to figure out how to get the update to work in the first place, you'd be far better off using a hook from the upstream to make it go.  You can do this simply with curl from a `post-commit` hook or if you're using github, just use a post-receive hook on their side.

Comment: A hook is much cleaner than using cron. Hooks are just scripts, so you can have something like `cd /path/to/production && git pull`.

Comment: Can I run post-commit hook as a 'nobody' ?

Comment: I tried this script (https://gist.github.com/737188) but have permission problem because the use running this script has no permission to the target directory

Comment: cron is self-contained and doesn't involve opening a potential security hole through a web service. Why do you think a webhook is better?

Comment: A webhook that fires only when changes will a) get the changes deployed faster and b) not leave you with thousands of processes consuming lots of resources on your machine when something goes wrong (even when nothing is changing).

Comment: How can you use hooks when you have to deploy to multiple servers?

Comment: In environment where web servers are auto spinned and you dont even have idea what IP addresses will be - there would be complicate task to create "hooks" even though it would be cleaner, but I vote for cron's simplicity of git pull.

Comment: Imagine my case, where we have a cluster of multiple NodeJS servers and a Git Server, and we want to keep production code up to date on all those servers from the Git Server, but we can't garantee that when a developer pushes production code to the Git Server that all NodeJS servers are UP.

Answer (score 8):

```
*/1 * * * * su -s /bin/sh nobody -c 'cd /home/heilee/src/project && /usr/bin/git pull origin master'
```

This corrects a couple errors that prevented the accepted answer from working on my system (Ubuntu >10.04 server). The key change seems to be the `-q` after the `pull` rather than before. You won't notice that your pull isn't working until you tail the `/var/log/syslog` file or try to run your non-updated production code.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from Git version [1.8.5 (Q4 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5fd09df3937f54c5cfda4f1087f5d99433cce527/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L115-L116) you can use the -C argument to easily accomplish this. Then you don't need to cd into the Git project directory but can instead specify it as part of the Git command like this:

```
*/15 * * * * git -C /home/me/gitprojectdir pull
```

Answer (score 6):

At the time of writing this answer, all the suggested solutions start with `cd`'ing into the working directory. Personally I would prefer to use the `git-dir` argument as so.

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/project/.git pull
```

For my own purposes, I'm using this cron to keep my local dev box up to date with what the other developers. Hence I'm using `fetch` instead of `pull`

```
*/15 * * * * git --git-dir=/home/andey/path/.git fetch -a
```

To simplify the current accepted solution, using the `git-dir` argument

```
*/1 * * * * su -s /bin/sh nobody -c '/usr/local/bin/git --git-dir=~dstrt/www pull origin master'
```

Comment: `git-dir` argument seemed to pull changes into the current directory. I wonder why there's no mention of `pushd`/`popd`.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/your_folder/your_folder && /usr/bin/git pull git@bitbucket.org:your_user/your_file.git
```

that is has been using by me and worked

Comment: @YudaPrawira, you are confusing `&` with `&&` — [further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26770612/884640)

Answer (score 3):

I create a small script to deal with it.Then can use the by command crontab

```
crontab -e
0 2 * * * cd /root && ./gitpull.sh > /root/log/cron.log  2>&1 &
```

Here are the `gitpull.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /etc/profile
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin
export PATH
export TERM=${TERM:-dumb}

#----------------------------------------
# Please set the following variable section
# Please set up working directories, use','split
# eg:path="/root/test/path1,/root/test/path2"
path=""
#----------------------------------------

# Do not edit the following section

# Check if user is root
[ $(id -u) != "0" ] && { echo "${CFAILURE}Error: You must run this script as root.${CEND}"; exit 1; } 2>&1

# Check if directory path exists
if [[ "${path}" = "" ]]; then 
    echo "${CFAILURE}Error: You must set the correct directory path.Exit.${CEND}" 2>&1
    exit 1
fi

# Check if command git exists
if ! [ -x "$(command -v git)" ]; then
    echo "${CFAILURE}Error: You may not install the git.Exit.${CEND}" 2>&1
    exit 1
fi

# Check where is command git
git_path=`which git`

# Start to deal the set dir
OLD_IFS="$IFS" 
IFS="," 
dir=($path) 
IFS="$OLD_IFS" 

echo "Start to execute this script." 2>&1

for every_dir in ${dir[@]} 
do 
    cd ${every_dir}
    work_dir=`pwd`
    echo "---------------------------------" 2>&1
    echo "Start to deal" ${work_dir} 2>&1
    ${git_path} pull
    echo "---------------------------------" 2>&1
done

echo "All done,thanks for your use." 2>&1
```

We have to set the work directory

Comment: You'll have to make the `gitpull.sh` script executable by running `chmod +x gitpull.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same thing, and I highly recommend pulling the branch like this:

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

So that it pulls origin master and merges into local master regardless on what branch you're in. Doesn't checkout you, doesn't interrupt your work (except you may encounter a git lock, which isn't gonna be long anyway, considering you pull it every half an hour).

Also, the whole string (every working day, every half an hour + every hour):

```
0,30 * * * 1-5 cd ~/work/project && git fetch origin master:master
0 * * * * 1-5 cd ~/work/project && git prune
```

If you need to make a monorepo faster, it's a really good thing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the same branch happens to be checked out at the moment.