# Remove 'credential-osxkeychain'

Tags: macos, git, credentials

I tried adding 'credential-osxkeychain' I followed [these steps](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git), but it has not installed correctly. I no longer want it. How can I stop git from calling it (when I do a pull)? Thank you!

```
git pull

git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Username for 'https://github.com': jzone3
Password for 'https://jzone3@github.com': 
git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Comment: What version of `git` are you using? Per the docs you cite, the crednetial helper isn't a command before v1.7.10.

Comment: Okay I was on an older version (1.7.9.6). I just updated to the newest version (1.7.12), but the problem persists.

Comment: It still claims it's not a git command?

Comment: Yes. Is there a way for me to reset the file that 'git config --global' is editing?

Comment: Sure. You can edit it directly with `git config --global --edit`. Just remove the offending line / section entirely.

Comment: [You can find more info on configuring this helper tool here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31351376/1922144)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ended up deleting osxkeychain from the config file.

```
git config --global --edit
```

Comment: Thanks for your help...I used this command directly: **git config --global --remove-section credential**

Answer (score 6):

It seems MacPorts packages the keychain helper and that might be why it wasn't coming up as a recognized command for you.

You can install the helper directly by following these instructions:

via: Magnus Johansson @ http://insomniacgeek.com/how-to-add-your-git-password-in-the-mac-osx-keychain/

In order to not having enter your git based password every time you perform a git operation, here’s how you can store the git password in the Mac OSX keychain:

Check if you have the credential-osxkeychain helper already installed:

git credential-osxkeychain

If not, the download and install it:

curl http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain -o git-credential-osxkeychain
sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain

And make git use the helper:

git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain

Answer (score 1):

> git config --global --remove-section credential