# How to remove git-credential-osxkeychain for good?

Tags: git, credentials

My problem: after installing git-credential-osxkeychain whenever I type "git" on the command line, I get this response:

```
Usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>
```

When I type any other git command such as `git pull` then a blank line appears and I have to press return to get back to the command line. If I type anything else but return, I get `bad input: ...` This means git command line is totally foobar! Though Tower continues to work.

The same behavior occurs when I run /usr/bin/git - just to be sure there aren't two conflicting git commands. I also re-installed git to no avail.

**I want my git back!!!** :/

[I already read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745504/remove-credential-osxkeychain) and it didn't help because osxkeychain isn't actually in the .gitconfig file since git started with this behavior the moment I moved git-credential-osxkeychain to the git directory (I followed this [setup guide](http://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git)). So the last command where it should have added it to .gitconfig had already broken git.

I thought, well, I'll just remove the git-credential-osxkeychain file and be done with it. If only I could find the file. It's not where I moved it to, it's not in a couple other "bin" places I looked either.

Answer (score -1):

I did a stupid thing. I copied git-credential-osxkeychain to the right directory but overwrote the git command with it. D'oh!