# Git Desktop error " ! [remote rejected] master -> master (permission denied)"

Tags: git, github

After forking a repo (Repo A) to Repo B, I've cloned a copy onto my PC using Git Desktop. I've then rolled back Repo B to an older commit using CLI and now want to push the change using Git Desktop. I keep getting a permission denied error.

I have added the lines for Windows 10 as per [how to log out of one Github account and use another account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351359/how-to-log-out-of-one-github-account-and-use-another-account) however it makes no difference, still having the same issue.

Running git push from the CLI and entering my credentials, I still get "! [remote rejected] master -> master (permission denied) error: failed to push some refs to'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you are pushing to your fork (repoB), a repo that you own.

Second, make sure the master branch is not protected against push.
And make sure to use a git push --force, if you have reset your branch to an older commit.

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222302/user1222302) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976794/git-desktop-error-remote-rejected-master-master-permission-denied/51978605#comment90913048_51978605):

> The repo was created with a new account and I'm still logged into the desktop with my personal account

The idea for pushing to a fork remains to push to a repo that you own. The account must match.

Comment: Man I'm an idiot, The repo was created with a new account and I'm still logged into the desktop with my personal account. 

All good now.

Comment: @user1222302 Great! Glad you spotted the issue.