# cron git push with ssh key

Tags: git, ssh, cron

I setup a ssh key for github account, so I don't have to enter the password every time, it works fine. Here is the script I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
git push origin master
```

But when I use cron to run it, it will not use my ssh key. Here is the output:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I search around and found some articles, but none of them solve my problem. Here are the articles I found(and a lot more):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/110565/why-is-git-not-using-my-pubkey-with-crontab

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35466/how-to-perform-git-push-using-crontab

[git push via cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994663/git-push-via-cron)

Can anybody give me a step to step instructions to solve this problem?

Comment: Does your ssh private key have a passphrase? If yes, when/how do you normally enter the passphrase to unlock the key?

Comment: @janos no passphrase, so I don't have to enter the password.I want it automatic.

Comment: You say the script works when you run in the shell, but not when you run in cron. Is cron running as the same user or different one? For example, maybe you run in the shell with user `jack`, but in cron you run it with user `root` ?

Comment: @janos same user, I edit with `crontab -u jack -e`, and `crontab -l` contains that job.

Comment: @xfx note that the -u option is given, it specifies the name of the user whose crontab is to be tweaked, not that the cron will be run by anyone else but root.

Comment: @NBhargav yes, by the answer of VonC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in one of [your thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/110573/5470), you need to point the root user which executes your cron script to the right `HOME` (the one which contains `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)`, your public and private keys.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOME=/home/yourAccount git push origin master
```

If that doesn't work, start debugging your ssh command with

```
#!/bin/bash
HOME=/home/yourAccount ssh -Tvvv yourGitServer
```

And check that with first a simple private key (not protected by a passphrase).
Then, if you need a passphrase, make sure your [ssh-agent is running](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases) in order to cache said passphrase (or using keychain, [as I mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7994919/6309)).

According to [your logs](https://dpaste.de/KLkJ), the public ssh key is proposed, but rejected.

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jack/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/jack/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Double-check "[BitBucket Set up SSH for Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git)", and make sure your `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` are there, **[with the right protection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13428529/6309)**.

Check also your `id_rsa.pub` has been added to your BitBucket account (as *one* line).

[image: https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/304578655/ssh_key.png?version=2&modificationDate=1379979345091&api=v2&effects=drop-shadow]

Comment: Still not working, here is the mail I got when run `ssh -Tvvv` From: root@myserver.localdomain (Cron Daemon)
To: jack@myserver.localdomain
Subject: Cron <jack@myserver> /home/jack/cron.sh
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/jack>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=jack>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=jack>
Message-Id: <20131231075601.59C95C0218@myserver.localdomain>
Date: Tue, 31 Dec 2013 15:56:01 +0800 (CST)

/bin/sh: /home/jack/cron.sh: Permission Denied

Comment: @xfx you can edit your answer to include the full output of the ssh -Tvvv command. That will be easier to debug.

Comment: @xfx it seems /home/jack/cron.sh is not executable... `chmod +x` on it and try again

Comment: @xfx and what is your remote url for origin?

Comment: @VonC hold on, I am trying.

Comment: Yes! What was missing?

Comment: @VonC, my key name is not id_rsa, it's id_ras_jack, so ssh cannot find it. I am search for config the name of key now.

Comment: @xfx stick with the default name, or use a ~/.ssh/config file, as mentioned below.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your comments, I don't really understand why your script wouldn't work in cron. We can try a few things to clear things up.

Add a configuration in `~/.ssh/config` for the user running the cron job like this:

```
Host github-project1
User git
HostName github.com
IdentityFile /path/to/github.project1.key
#or like this:
#IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github.project1.key
```

Then in your git working tree add a new remote like this:

```
git remote add github-project1 github-project1:USER/PROJECT.git
```

In the url there, `github-project1:user/project.git`, change only `USER` and `PROJECT` to the right values for your project, but leave `github-project1` as is: it must match the value of the `Host` setting in the `ssh` configuration we just added.

Finally, change the script to use this new remote:

```
#!/bin/bash
git push github-project1 master
```

Test the script first in the shell, and then in cron.