# git pull automatic via crontab

Tags: git, cron

I would like to sync my git repository on my server to my local webserver. All the guides I read caused different errors and now I'm really desperate. I'm sorry if you already read this question a hundred times, but I still don't get it -.-

- Working with Linux SuSE and conneting on it with PuTTY via SSH
- the webprojekt where I need the sync is on the folder: /srv/www/htdocs/my_project
- the git repository is here: /srv/git/repository/my_project
- I have the users: "root" and "cron"

The cron should do this commands every minute or less with the user "cron":

```
cd /srv/www/htdocs/my_project
git pull origin
(git fetch) <-- not mandatory
```

These commands work fine when I input them manually. (except I have to enter the user password every time)

[In this question I got some informations, but I always get an error when I try them myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414140/git-auto-pull-using-cronjob/4415927#4415927).

My cron should look like this then:

```
* * * * * su -s /bin/sh cron -c 'cd /srv/www/htdocs/my_project && /usr/local/bin/git pull origin master'
```

I executed this on my PuTTY, which answered me: **-bash: bin: command not found**

My next try was:

```
crontab * * * * * su -s /bin/sh cron -c 'cd /srv/www/htdocs/my_project && /usr/local/bin/git pull origin master'
```

**Error: crontab: invalid option -- 's'**

**Error: crontab: usage error: unrecognized option**

I tried a lot more combinations (removing the su -s or removing the -c etc.) but it never worked as I wanted -.- Shouldn't I do this command on PuTTY?

Good to know: I'm a linux and GIT beginner, started working with it yesterday and actually managed to do a lot til now. (*^.^*) So I would be happy to have an understandable explanation, in what I do wrong and what I have to do. It's confusing.

Comment: A cronjob is not the best way to do this. Where is your git repository hosted?

Comment: the repository is not hosted somewhere. On the the server I have apache, gitolite and the git repository. We don't use github.com if this was your idea. I want to use thiy system for internal testing, before we upload the projects to the live server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want (have the git repository automatically deployed on your server) is by putting the git repository inside you webserver and using a hook to do a check out on push. How to this is described in this answer: [Deploy a project using Git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git-push)