# '&&' vs. '&' with the 'test' command in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Consider:

```
gndlp@ubuntu:~$ test -x examples.desktop  && echo $?
gndlp@ubuntu:~$ test -x examples.desktop  & echo $?
[1] 2992
0
```

Why is Bash acting the way it is in this situation?

Is the test command simply not finishing and thus the `echo` command isn't processed?

Comment: You don't explain the behavior you expect. What about this is surprising? Why is it surprising? What expectation does it contradict?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The meaning of `&&` and `&` are intrinsically different.

- **What is `&&` in Bash?** In Bash — and many other programming languages — `&&` means “AND”. And in command execution context like this, it means items to the left as well as right of `&&` should be run in sequence in this case.
- **What is `&` in Bash?** And a single `&` means that the preceding commands — to the immediate left of the `&` — should simply be run in the background.

So looking at your example:

```
gndlp@ubuntu:~$ test -x examples.desktop  && echo $?
gndlp@ubuntu:~$ test -x examples.desktop  & echo $?
[1] 2992
0
```

The first command—as it is structured—actually does not return anything. But second command returns a `[1] 2992` in which the `2992` refers to the process ID (PID) that is running in the background and the `0` is the output of the first command.

Since the second command is just running `test -x examples.desktop` in the background it happens quite quickly, so the process ID is spawned and gone pretty immediately.

Answer (score 22):

`&` executes a command in the background, and will return 0 regardless of its status.

From [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0. Commands separated by a ; are executed sequentially; the shell waits for each command to terminate in turn. The return status is the exit status of the last command executed.

Answer (score 9):

Look at what your commands are:

```
test -x examples.desktop  && echo $?
```

This means check to see if `examples.desktop` is executable and if it is then execute `echo $?`.

```
test -x examples.desktop  & echo $?
```

means check to see if `examples.desktop` is executable in the "background". Then execute `echo $?`.