# Multiple commands in gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

I want to execute multiple commands using `gulp` to start a server. I want to execute the following commands with the `gulp` task.

```
- cd ../server
- npm run start
```

I was trying `gulp-exec`, ... etc and those didn't work.

```
exec('cd ../server & npm run start')
```

How to achieve this using the `gulp` task?

Comment: try `exec('cd ../server && npm run start')`; with two `&` chars, difference can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770568/vs-with-the-test-command-in-bash)

Comment: Tried with "&", "&&", "|". None of them worked.

Comment: provide more information about the folder structure, provide the task from the package.json file inside the `server` directory

Comment: It worked with var exec = require('child_process').exec; Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying with gulp-exec and didn't work.

Later tried this and it worked.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
gulp.task('start', function(){
    exec('cd ../server && npm run start-windows');
});
```

Comment: is it not giving gulp as undefined ?