# Run pip in (conda) virtualenv without activating it first

Tags: pip, virtualenv, conda

As in the title, I've created some env in conda like so

```
conda create -n myenv python=2.7
```

I'd like a command to run `pip install` inside the env without doing `source activate myenv` first.  Is this possible?  I believe whatever method I use would have to work out the PATH etc.

Comment: By default, environments are created at `/path/to/anaconda/envs/env-name`, you can look there. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @darthbith Useful if you have a python script to create multiple environments to set up a new user. I've gotten it to work with conda run -n [env_name] pip install [dependency] or something similar. But, it's not working right now on Windows. Any idea?

Comment: @illan If you're creating multiple environments to set up a new user, I'd suggest using `environment.yml` files, which can already encode `pip` dependencies. Then you don't need to run pip for anything.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Anaconda in a Bash shell environment, one option would be to add the Anaconda bin path for your created virtual environment to your `PATH` variable in such an order that the pip binary in your virtual environment comes before the system pip.

If your Anaconda virtual environment is located in the default `.conda` directory in your home directory you could do this as follows:

```
export PATH=~/.conda/envs/myenv/bin:$PATH
```

If you wanted this to be the default behavior for your shell environment you could add the above command to your `~/.bashrc` file.

This method is similar to the approach reccomended for setting the `PATH` variable to enable you to use the Anaconda binaries for the "root" environment, [detailed in the Anaconda documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#installing-anaconda).

Comment: link is outdated now?

Comment: Thanks @Matifou. I've just fixed the broken link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible! Conda run does the same as conda activate / command / conda deactivate.

```
command_install = f'conda run -n {env_name} python -m pip install {shared_dep}'
```

So, for example:

```
conda run -n nlp python -m pip install transformers
```

Note that you must first install pip in the environment. Otherwise, the environment's pip is a link to the system pip and everything will install to the base python/conda interpreter.

```
conda install -n nlp pip -y
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution that may work for you (it worked for me to script pip installs from command line) is to use `&` to tunnel commands. For instance:

`conda create -n myenv python=2.7 & conda activate myenv & pip install {some packages} & conda deactivate`

That works for me on Windows machines and it should work the same way on Linux as well.
[Information regarding the & command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770568/vs-with-the-test-command-in-bash)

However due to the way that pip is set up I don't think there's a way around activating the environment first. Hope this at least helps!