# How to run multiple gradle bootRun at startup on OSX?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to edit `bash_profile` to run two gradle repos at startup, but it doesn't seem to work. I can only run one and the other one never gets to run. Also, whenever I open a new terminal window, it tries to run again. I just want to run it once at startup, so I don't have to run it manually every time. This is what I added in `bash_profile`

```
./zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/zkServer.sh start
./repo1/gradew bootRun && /repo2/gradew bootRun
```

Comment: just change `&&` to `&`, because your first Spring Boot app never complete execution https://stackoverflow.com/a/26770612/8112217

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work :( I never see the second service up and running.