# Docker image - SpringBoot and Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, shell, docker-compose, dockerfile

**SCENARIO**: I've build a microservice to solve a business requirement in Pentaho, that is a application above a tomcat, running in different port, of course, because my application as standalone get in conflict with Pentaho libraries when run in a docker container. I would like to run this two applications in just one docker image because this application is specific to Pentaho and will be installed in users machine, so it's easier to maintain. I put the jar of microservice inside Pentaho but when docker compose try to run this image only start microservice.

run.sh:

```
if [ -z "$DEBUG" ]; then
  echo Starting Sheet Formatting service and Pentaho in DEBUG mode
  cd /pentaho/
  java -jar sheet-service.jar && 
  cd *server*
  ./start-pentaho.sh;
else
  echo Starting Sheet Formatting service and Pentaho in normal mode
  cd /pentaho/
  java -jar sheet-service.jar &&
  cd *server*
  ./start-pentaho-debug.sh;
fi
```

Dockerfile:

```
....
EXPOSE 8080 8889

# 1. Run 

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/pentaho/run.sh"]
```

Microservice directory:
/pentaho/sheet-service.jar

Start Pentaho directory:
/pentaho/pentaho-server/start-pentaho.sh
/pentaho/pentaho-server/start-pentaho-debug.sh

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to run Spring Boot application and Tomcat in the same container?

Comment: Probably you meant &, not && (run.sh). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770568/vs-with-the-test-command-in-bash/26770612

Comment: @Mayfor The first script needs to run in background to run the second script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed && to & as @Mafor said and it worked.

```
if [ -z "$DEBUG" ]; then
  echo Starting Sheet Formatting service and Pentaho in DEBUG mode
  cd /pentaho/
  java -jar cup-cap-sheet-service.jar & 
  cd *server*
  ./start-pentaho.sh;
else
  echo Starting Sheet Formatting service and Pentaho in normal mode
  cd /pentaho/
  java -jar cup-cap-sheet-service.jar &
  cd *server*
  ./start-pentaho-debug.sh;
fi
```