# Environment variable is still undefined after being set

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, environment-variables, package.json

I am trying to set my environment variable within package.json so that I can use it within my server.js file. I have set it as `NODE_ENV=development`, `set NODE_ENV=development`,
`cross-env NODE_ENV=development`, `export NODE_ENV=development` but it is still returning undefined. I am not sure what is going wrong but I would love any insight into this problem!

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "NODE_ENV=development npm run client & npm run start & npm run json-server & redis-server"
}
```

server.js

```
//returns undefined
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be using [`&& instead of &`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770568/vs-with-the-test-command-in-bash#:~:text=The%20meaning%20of%20%26%26%20and,in%20sequence%20in%20this%20case.)...

Answer (score 0):

> I am not entirely sure how your file is structure but it seems you got
> some of the command wrong.
>
> You should use `set NODE_ENV=development` and you should double
> ampersand

> Honestly it much easier to define it in your main server file like
> this:
>
> ```
> const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install and require the dotenv package and did you call the .config() function of it in your index.js ? This will probably help.