# Why docker-compose is not running my commands sequentially?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is my docker-compose file
It does not even run wait_for_db command
I tried to put the commands in a bash script but it didn't work also

If somebody could help me writing these commands
I want to run manage.py commands and also
run celer and celery beat

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: >
      sh -c "
            python app/manage.py wait_for_db &&
            python app/manage.py makemigrations &&
            python app/manage.py makemigrations csvreader &&
            python app/manage.py migrate &&
            python app/manage.py wait_for_migrate &&
            python app/manage.py create_admin --username admin --password admin --noinput --email admin@admin.com &&
            python app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &
            celery -A app --workdir app worker --loglevel=info &
            celery -A app --workdir app beat -l INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler "
    volumes:
      - .:/djangoapp
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "23:22"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - broker
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_NAME=mycsv
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - CELERY_BROKER=amqp://admin:password@broker:5672//
    restart: on-failure


  db:
    image: postgres:13.3-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mycsv
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  broker:
    image: rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password
```

And here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /djangoapp
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev build-essential
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 22
COPY . /djangoapp
```

It seems that none of the commands are being run

Comment: Please share more details - that might all depend on whatever that `manage.py` contains

Comment: Also on what's in the image; does the Dockerfile have an `ENTRYPOINT` line?  It looks like you're trying to run three separate processes in that container, should it be three separate containers?

Comment: Also, is there any reason you are using a single `&` sometimes, and a double one for the other commands? That makes a huge difference (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770568/vs-with-the-test-command-in-bash)