# Is there a way to combine CMD command and Git Bash command into one alias

Tags: bash, git, cmd

I have been trying to combine "clear" and "git status" as one command into one git alias. Is there a way to achieve this??
I have tried the following :

```
git config --global alias.clearall 'clear && git status'
```

and also the same using `nano ~/.bashrc` and add the same alias.

But both don't work. So can anyone suggest another idea ?

Comment: What is the meaning of "don't work"? How do you know that it "didn't work"?

Comment: Indeed it doesn't work, but the point here is ... well, see [ask] and [mre]. Post good *questions!*

Answer (score 0):

Notice in git config you write git commands only for example:

> `git config --global alias.chst '!git checkout && git status'`

Call alias command with `git + aliasNAME`:

> `git chst`

For more information [view this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66717011/5661396)

But you can alias from `~/.bashrc` open `~/.bashrc`  with any editor that you have for example `nano ~/.bashrc` and write alias it:

> `alias clearall="clear && git status"`

Call it this command from `git bash` by writing alias name:

> `clearall`

Comment: `&` is most likely wrong. Do you mean `&&`?

Comment: @j6t I updated the answer but it work in Windows OS

Comment: `&` may "work" for some definition of "work", but it is most likely wrong anyway. Please read up on what the [difference between `&` and `&&`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26770612/6868543) is.