# A new git project from a branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a project on Github and I started a slightly different version of it on another branch.

I want now to separate that branch into a separate project, which could be synchronized with the original project, so when I make some changes in the original project, i could also pull them to the new branch (but not the other way round).

What is the best procedure for that?

I could, of course, just copy the branch files into a new folder and initialize a new repo then push it to Github, but I'm sure there's a better way of doing what I want, I just don't know how...

Thank you!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414140/git-auto-pull-using-cronjob) might help you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting, but my goal is not to automatically keep the branch updated. Rather, I want it to be an independent separate project, which can be still integrated with the original one if the need arises.

Comment: github itself doesn't support this, but as branches are just pointers to commits you can do this manually... create a new project, clone your old one locally, rename the branches, push it to the new github remote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want now to separate that branch into a separate project, which
>   could be synchronized with the original project, so when I make some
>   changes in the original project, i could also pull them to the new
>   branch (but not the other way round).

1. Create a new project in GitHub
2. In your existing project, check out the branch of interest.

   ```
   git checkout mybranch
   ```
3. Push it into the `master` branch of your new project:

   ```
   git push git@github.com:username/project.git mybranch:master
   ```

Now the `master` branch of your new project contains the history of `mybranch` in your exist project.

To keep the new repository in sync:

1. Add it as a new "remote" to your existing repository:

   ```
   git remote add otherproject git@github.com:username/project.git
   ```
2. When you make changes to `mybranch`, push them to the `master` branch of `otherproject`:

   ```
   git push otherproject mybranch:master
   ```

Comment: Thank you! And how will I pull the changes from my original project into the new one then?